# current_prolog_flag double_quotes DCG (codes or chars)?

Tags: prolog, flags, dcg

In using SWI Prolog DCGs I noticed some people note

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
```

[Jan](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings)

while others note

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

[false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/1243762), [Markus](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg), [mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871568/1243762)

What is the difference if any when using with DCG and phrase?

### References

[The string type and its double quoted syntax](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings)
  [DCG](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)
  [DCG Grammar rules](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG)
  [double_quotes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags)
  [set_prolog_flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_prolog_flag/2)

Comment: Where did I **ever** endorse `codes`? I  said: *This is frequently the default, but it leads to very unreadable answers*.  By what collusion can this be seen as a preference/recommendation let alone endorsement?

Comment: @false I changed it. As I often note, this is all CC so feel free to change it.

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [5.6 Remaining issues](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-issues) - Codes can be used in arithmetic expressions, while chars are more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name `double_quotes` implies, this flag affects how **double quotes** (i.e.: `"`) are treated.

This holds whether or not such quotes are used in connection with DCGs. However, it is especially useful in connection with DCGs because you can for example use:

```
?- phrase(nt(NT), "test").
```

and thus automatically treat the phrase to be parsed as a list of characters (in this case: `[t,e,s,t]`). That's nice for interactive test cases.

The [**answer by false**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/1613573) that you linked to explains it nicely. Note also the following quote from the answer:

> This notation [using **chars**!] gives **more readable answers**. It can be even more compactly displayed since the double quote notation can be used for printing any list of one-char atoms.

It is clear that **chars** yields more readable answers than `codes`. For example:

```
?- Xs = "hello".
Xs = [h, e, l, l, o].
```

vs., with `codes`:

```
?- Xs = "hello".
Xs = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111].
```

(*Ahem*.)

Historically, <s>[Han shot first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_shot_first)</s> chars came first! Only later, this was changed to using codes by default. A quite unfortunate choice, in my view. Other languages like Haskell work like Prolog originally did:

```
Hugs> :t last
last :: [a] -> a
Hugs> :t "test"
"test" :: String
Hugs> last "test"
't'
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but it is considered one of the most glaring blemishes on Haskell though since strings in Haskell actually _are_ linked lists of characters (unless you use ByteStrings or Text).

Comment: This only means that someone will have to implement an optimization that increases the efficiency of the *internal* representation of strings in the Haskell runtime. Surely it cannot be considered a blemish that strings can be so naturally reasoned about at the *application* level, no?

Comment: I don't know the internals well enough to comment, but I wouldn't assume that it would be easy to make your suggested change.

Comment: I'm sure it's either not easy or not *that* much of a problem. Still, I think the Haskell approach is much nicer than what other systems have done, such as: *That's hard, so let's break something else instead of getting this right.* I think it's not a blemish to stay true to elegant principles, even if they come at a price for the moment. I do not think that this particular issue is holding Haskell back very much by itself, although I can of course imagine use cases where it could be a problem.