How to implement CFG in Prolog?
I am trying to implement a parser in prolog for this grammar:
Lines → Line ; Lines | Line
Line → Num , Line | Num
Num → Digit | Num
Digit → 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

the code is:
parse(X) :- lines([X|T],T).

lines(X,A) :- line(X, Y), simecolon(Y, Z), lines(Z, A).
lines(X, Y) :- line(X, Y).

line(X, A) :- num(X, Y), comma(Y, Z), line(Z, A).
line(X, Y) :- num(X, Y).

%num(X, Y) :- num(X, Y).
%num(X, A) :- digit(X,A).
%num(X, Y) :- digit(X,T), num(T,Y).
num(X, Y) :- digit(X,Y).

simecolon([';' | T], T).
comma([',' | T], T).

digit([X | T], T) :-
   X = '0';
   X = '1';
   X = '2';
   X = '3';
   X = '4';
   X = '5';
   X = '6';
   X = '7';
   X = '8';
   X = '9'.

the code is not giving true if the sentence or list in the grammar. for example this should be true, but code gives false:
?- parse(['3', '2', ',', '0', ';', '1', ',', '5', '6', '7', ';', '2']).

can anybody help me in this code?

Firstly: use DCG, for more elegant code. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870994/how-do-i-specify-a-dcg-for-a-valid-number

I think your grammar is incorrect. The Num rule looks fishy to me.

Learn how to use your Prolog's debugger!  Things go wrong pretty quickly:
(1) 1 CALL  parse(['3', '2', ',', ...])
(2) 2 CALL  lines([['3', '2', ...]|_755], _755)

Your parse/1 should simply be
parse(Cs) :- lines(Cs, []).

Then uncomment your recursive clause in num/2, giving
num(X, Y) :- digit(X,T), num(T,Y).
num(X, Y) :- digit(X,Y).

and everything works!

Notably, you have fixed the error in the Num rule with this implementation
